# UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libhello in java.library.path

Tags: java, c, linux, eclipse, java-native-interface

I'm doing a tutorial about JNI to get comfortable with it for my project. However, I'm stuck on this particular part of the tutorial which is running the Java program. I'm using Eclipse where I've created a Java project and put the files inside a package. When I try to follow the tutorial without using Eclipse, I get no errors, so I assume it's a path related issue.

As for my error, I get an

> UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libhello in java.library.path

when I run this in my terminal:

```
java -Djava.library.path=. helloJNI.HelloJNI
```

Even when I specify my path, it doesn't work. If you want to reproduce my steps, here's what I did:

1. After creating `HelloJNI.java`, I ran the following in the terminal:

   ```
   javac -h . HelloJNI.java
   ```

This command created the generated header file given below.

2. After this, I wrote `HelloJNI.c`, navigated to the package folder and then compiled it using this command in the same directory:

   ```
    gcc -fPIC -I"$JAVA_HOME/include" -I"$JAVA_HOME/include/linux" -shared -o libhello.so HelloJNI.c
   ```
3. Then I moved up one directory to `~/eclipse-workspace/HelloJNI/src` and ran this command:

   ```
    java -Djava.library.path=. HelloJNI
   ```

Which yields the error described above.

Here's my code:

**HelloJNI.java**

```
package helloJNI;

public class HelloJNI {  // Save as HelloJNI.java
       static {
          System.loadLibrary("hello"); // Load native library hello.dll (Windows) or libhello.so (Unixes)
                                       //  at runtime
                                       // This library contains a native method called sayHello()
       }

       // Declare an instance native method sayHello() which receives no parameter and returns void
       private native void sayHello();

       // Test Driver
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          new HelloJNI().sayHello();  // Create an instance and invoke the native method
       }
    }
```

**HelloJNI.c**

```
// Save as "HelloJNI.c"
#include <jni.h>        // JNI header provided by JDK
#include <stdio.h>      // C Standard IO Header
#include "helloJNI_HelloJNI.h"   // Generated

// Implementation of the native method sayHello()
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
   printf("Hello World!\n");
   return;
}
```

**helloJNI_HelloJNI.h**

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class helloJNI_HelloJNI */

#ifndef _Included_helloJNI_HelloJNI
#define _Included_helloJNI_HelloJNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     helloJNI_HelloJNI
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_helloJNI_HelloJNI_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

I have also tried setting the path to my working directory, but I still get the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> I moved up one directory to `~/eclipse-workspace/HelloJNI/src`

This means that your **libhello.so** is in `~/eclipse-workspace/HelloJNI/src/helloJNI` directory, isn't it?

Now, to let Java find this library, run

```
java -Djava.library.path=helloJNI helloJNI.HelloJNI
```

or use the absolute path

```
java -Djava.library.path=~/eclipse-workspace/HelloJNI/src/helloJNI helloJNI.HelloJNI
```

Comment: Yes, my libhello.so file is in the helloJNI directory. I tried your suggestions. It seems to fix the problem, but then I get a different error. Now it says: Error: Could not find or load main class HelloJNI Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloJNI

Comment: The error still persists even with the prefix, unfortunately.

Comment: You are supposed to run this command when `~/eclipse-workspace/HelloJNI/src` is your current directory

Comment: I see, but running the command from ``~/eclipse-workspace/HelloJNI/src`` produces the old error. I've also tried editing my ``LD_LIBRARY_PATH`` by adding my workspace directory, though with no luck.

Comment: make sure you have files `~/eclipse-workspace/HelloJNI/src/helloJNI/HelloJNI.class` and `~/eclipse-workspace/HelloJNI/src/helloJNI/libhello.so`.

Comment: I did make sure of that, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: No. But I'm pretty sure I need it.

Comment: *"I'm pretty sure I need it"* Oh, I didn't express myself correctly.What I wanted to suggest: perform minimal change to this Java class so that it does not need the native lib, check that in your environment it now works as expected, and only after that try to find what must be done to have the native lib work, too.

Comment: Hi, I figured it out. I forgot to add the package name in the function inside the C file... Embarrassing. Thanks for your help anyway.